# Python CSV Comparison

Tags: python, csv, comparison

This script compares two csv files...with two columns plz help me to modify this script if sample1.csv and sample2.csv has more than 2 columns or 1 column.

```
f1_in = open("sample1.csv","r")
next(f1_in,None)
f1_dict = {}
for line in f1_in:
  l = line.split(',')
  f1_dict[l[0]. strip()] = l[1]. strip() 
  l.sort()
f1_in.close()

f2_in = open("sample2.csv","r")
next(f2_in,None)
f2_dict = {}
for line in f2_in:
  l = line.split(',')
  f2_dict[l[0]. strip()] = l[1]. strip()
  l.sort()
f2_in.close()


f_same = open("same.txt","w")
f_different = open("different.txt","w")

for k1 in f1_dict.keys():
  if k1 in f2_dict.keys() \
      and f2_dict[k1] == f1_dict[k1]:
    f_same.write("{0}, {1}\n". format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                    str(k1)+" "+str(f2_dict[k1])))

  elif not k1 in f2_dict.keys():
    f_different.write("{0}, {1}\n". format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                           "------"))
  elif not f2_dict[k1] == f1_dict[k1]:
    f_different.write("{0}, {1}\n". format(str(k1)+" "+str(f1_dict[k1]),
                                           str(k1)+" "+str(f2_dict[k1])))

f_same.close()
f_different.close()
```

for eg:if my source file has Name and Salary as headers with values A 20000 B 15000 C 10000 D 10000 and target file also with Name and Salary has headers with values A 40000 D 10000 B 15000 C 10000 E 8000...my output should be Different lines:A 20000 A 40000 D 10000 -----(no file in target) -----(no file in source) E 8000 and common lines as B 15000 B 15000, C 10000 C 10000

Comment: Well what are the problems you have in those cases? Do you get errors, or unexpected outputs? What have you tried so far to make the code more general?

Comment: Hy...jonrshape i am getting it correctly if i have just two columns to compare in source and target ...if there is 1 column and more than 2 column also...itz just taking only two columns for comparison...

Comment: So, again; *what have you tried so far*? Which bits of the code do you think are relevant to the number of columns? What data structure do you think would be appropriate for dealing with an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: i am pretty new to python even this code i got from stackoverflow only...i guess the last part where the comparison is made starting from  for k1 in f1_dict.keys(): is where the change should be made to read n number of column...

Comment: I suggest you put more effort into understanding the code you have now. Throw some `print`s in, figure out what's going on, and then you can work out how to modify it. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i got what is going on...how this code is working...but donno how to modify further...will be great if you could please help me on this.

Comment: Why not just use `csv` instead of reading files line by line? Relevant info can be found [here] [here]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

It is no wonder you cannot expand the code to more than two colums if you are regarding your columns as key/value pairs in a dictionary.

You have to see them as "elements in a set".  I understand this is why you are not using the `csv` module or the `difflib` module: because you do not care whether the lines appear in (nearly) same order in either file, but whether they appear at all.

Here is an example:

```
import itertools


def compare(first_filename, second_filename):
    lines1 = set()
    lines2 = set()
    with open(first_filename, 'r') as file1, \
            open(second_filename, 'r') as file2:
        for line1, line2 in itertools.izip_longest(file1, file2):
            if line1:
                lines1.add(line1)
            if line2:
                lines2.add(line2)
    print "Different lines"
    for line in lines1 ^ lines2:
        print line,
    print "---"
    print "Common lines"
    for line in lines1 & lines2:
        print line,
```

Notice that this code will find differences on both files, not just things that exist on f1 but not on f2, as your example does. However, it is not able to tell where do differences come from (since this does not seem a requirement of the question).

#### Check that it works

```
In [40]: !cat sample1.csv
bacon, eggs, mortar
whatever, however, whenever
spam, spam, spam

In [41]: !cat sample2.csv
guido, van, rossum
spam, spam, spam

In [42]: compare("sample1.csv", "sample2.csv")
Different lines
whatever, however, whenever
guido, van, rossum
bacon, eggs, mortar
---
Common lines
spam, spam, spam
```

Comment: logc...where should we input the filename?

Comment: @user3514648 : I am not sure I understand your question.  If the CSV files you want to compare are called "sample1.csv" and "sample2.csv", then open a Python console in the same directory, cut and paste the snippet above to the console, and then write `compare("sample1.csv", "sample2.csv")`.  Another method would be: write the snippet and the line mentioned before **without indentation** in a module `example.py`, and run `python example.py` in the same directory where the files are.

Comment: thanks...itz working but not in the exact way i want  for eg:if my source file has Name and Salary as headers with values 
A 20000
B 15000
C  10000
D 10000
and target file also with Name and Salary has headers with values A 40000
D 10000
B 15000
C 10000
E 8000...my output should be Different lines:A 20000 A 40000
 D 10000 -----(no file in target) -----(no file in source) E 8000 and common lines as B 15000 B 15000, C 10000 C 10000

Comment: @user3514648: I think you should write those informations in the question.  That will help others apart from me to help you out.

Comment: sorry...could u help me n dis?

Comment: You have to edit the question.  You should see a link called like that underneath the question.  Then just add beneath the existing text the example you have given to me in the previous comment.